# extract an email address from a text

Tags: apex

in apex code, i would like to extract an email address alone from a text like below.
Note: The domain name wont be the same.
please share if you have any idea?

**Example Text:**

Delivery has failed for the below recipient

sa1122112211@domain.co.uk

A problem occurred during the delivery of this message to this e-mail address. Try sending this message again. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

Comment: A good way for searching for sub strings is the rabin karp algorithm

Comment: Rest of the text is remaining static ?

Comment: No They are also not static... basically.. i want to find a first email address of a email body in Bounce back email. The bounce back email wont be having similar text, it may change based on the domain server.

Comment: In Short, i am trying to get the wrong email id for which the bounce back happened.

Comment: Email template should have some delimiter separating the email address , Or Some static content surround By the email address. See below Example , i use the word to extract the email address .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with Regex. You need to use `find()` and `group()`. As your text is not static so I used some junk text. Sample code for your reference.

```
String s = 'agfawig test@Test.com klaho;hfwaojfoiskfhnkh enesr eknnw rendafn owen';
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+').matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.debug(m.group());
    }
```

Comment: Great! its working but i am getting helpdesk email addresses which are present below the body. how can i ignore the other email ids? i need only the first email id. Please help

Comment: please refrain from asking follow up question in the comments, and rather post a new question. Thanks

Comment: @Tushar Thank you so much .. it works fine ... this is what i was looking for..

Answer (score 0):

```
//string EmailBody;// get the Email body from from the Mail;
```

**This piece of the code only work for the above email.**

```
string EmailBody = 'Delivery has failed for the below recipient' +
                    'sa1122112211@domain.co.uk' +
                    'A problem occurred during the delivery of this message to this e-mail address. Try sending this message again. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.';
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(?<=below recipient)(.*)(?=A problem)');
Matcher m = p.matcher(EmailBody);
if (m.find()) 
{
   system.debug(m.group(1)); 
}
```

Try to run the above code in anonymous window